# array from javascript to controller java in kendo ui

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a grid in kendo ui with batch editing and I need pass a array to my controller when user clicks update. I have the follow code:

index.jsp:

```
parameterMap: function(data, type) {
    if (type != "read") {
        data = data.models;
    }
    return data;
}
```

Controller.java:

```
@Post
@WithoutRoot
public void atualizar(List<MyClassViewModel> vm) {
    result.nothing();
}
```

This way, although the `data.models` containing an array of objects that were changed, my List returns empty. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `kendo.stringify`:

```
parameterMap: function(data, type) {
    if (type != "read") {
        data = kendo.stringify(data.models);
    }
    return data;
}
```

Not sure if this will fix your issue but I'm also using `batch: true` for my dataSource and this seems to be working for my view models.

You probably also want to check Chrome -> Developer Tools -> Network -> Headers-> Request Payload and see how your data is handed over to the server. Your `MyClassViewModel` property names should match exactly what you pass from the client.

Comment: My problem was another, but I solved. Thx for your answer! :-)